# View controller doesn't change after setting present controller

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, swift

I have MainViewController, which contains buttons(onclick pushViewController).
In inner page i write:

```
let vc = MainViewController(nibName: "View", bundle: nil);
self.navigationController?.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Buttons do not work after returning to MainViewController (onlick nothing happens)

Comment: Can you brief you steps in mode details?

Looks like you are doing push to second controller and then opening main controller again as present view controller?

Comment: In View.xib Maincontroller`s view there are buttons. If click on them i change viewcontroller by method pushviewcontroller. In the second controller`s view there are buttons to. Click on them i want change viewcontroller by method presentcontroller and go back to maincontroller. But after returning to maincontroller all buttons are clickble but without any action.

Answer (score 0):

ok. Issue here is with navigation.

1) You are opening second view with Push
2) You are again opening main view but with present

Issues:

1) Presented view controller must have navigation controller in order to do Push.

2) Why you want to present main view again. You can directly use popToRootView  method to go back on main view.

Comment: View controller has navigation controller. Because i want viewDidload method calls